# XSLT apply attribute to sibling instead of parent

Tags: html, xslt

Consider the following XSLT

```
<div class="name-input">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">mandatory</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:copy-of select="FIRSTNAME/*/input"/>
</div>
```

Generates this markup

```
<div class="pax-mandatory-field">
    <input type="text" id="FirstName" />
</div>
```

what I want is

```
<div class="name-input">
    <input type="text" id="FirstName" class="mandatory" />
</div>
```

I tried this instead (which didn't work)

```
<div class="name-input">
     <xsl:copy-of select="FIRSTNAME/*/input">
         <xsl:attribute name="class">mandatory</xsl:attribute>    
     </xsl:copy-of>
</div>
```

Not even sure where to start. Any ideas what needs changing?

Comment: Please include a sample input XML.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen The XML generated is 271KB long; though, the generated markup I have supplied is in the XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an input of this:

```
<FIRSTNAME>
    <ANYNODE>
        <input type="text" id="FirstName" />
    </ANYNODE>
</FIRSTNAME>
```

start first with an identity template

```
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

from the sample XML above, create an override template for `input`

```
<xsl:template match="FIRSTNAME/*/input">
    <!-- set container tags -->
    <div class="name-input">
        <!-- xsl:copy here copies the current node -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- applies the attributes if present -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <!-- sets the class attribute --> 
            <xsl:attribute name="class">mandatory</xsl:attribute> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

thus the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="FIRSTNAME/*/input">
        <div class="name-input">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="class">mandatory</xsl:attribute> 
            </xsl:copy>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

yields:

```
<FIRSTNAME>
    <ANYNODE>
        <div class="name-input">
           <input type="text" id="FirstName" class="mandatory"/>
        </div>
    </ANYNODE>
</FIRSTNAME>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works and how? I don't see how a code dump answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to change/add the attributes of the input you need to switch form `copy-of`to apply-templates. E.g as following:

Have a new template for "special" input element  handling  with an mode to avoid side effects  for other input elements.

```
<xsl:template match="input" mode="myfirst">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:attribute name="class">mandatory</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And than use it:

```
<div class="name-input">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="FIRSTNAME/*/input"  mode="myfirst" />
</div>
```